# how to use a .c file to write a test class in google test instead of .cpp file?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest

I have used googletest for my Android NDK project contain .c files. I have used a test class of the type .cpp to do the same. I want to use .c file instead. I get the following error when I try to use it :

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you care whether your file has a .c or .cpp file-name extension? Why not just use the one that works *and* accurately describes the contents of the file?

Comment: I get certain compilation issues which is unable to recognize the type conversions      
 error: cannot convert 'MyVersion {aka tagMYVersion}' to 'MyStatus' for argument '2'                                                     
 There are no such compilation issues when I run ndk-build alone for the project / when I compile my source code in a .c file instead of .cpp  , So wanted a way to run gtest using .c files

Comment: So it is working fine only for some parts of my c code!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot use a `.c` file to write a test class in googletest instead of a `.cpp` file.

A `.c` file should contain C language source code and a C/C++ compiler will assume that a `.c` file
is to be compiled as C.

A `.cpp` file should contain C++ language source code and a C/C++ compiler will assume that a `.cpp` file
is to be compiled as C++.

C and C++ are related but different programming languages. C is much older and simpler than C++.
There are no classes in the C language. C++ source code containing classes cannot be compiled as C.

Googletest is a unit-testing framework that is written in C++, not C, and it requires you to write
your test code in C++, using the framework classes. Your tests must coded in `.cpp` (and `.h`) files so that
the compiler will compile them as C++.

However, you *can* use googletest to unit-test C code. The C code will be in `.c` and `.h` files, but you
have to code your *unit-tests*, as usual, in `.cpp` and `.h` files. The C/C++ compiler knows that
the `.c` files are to be compiled as C and the `.cpp` files are to be compiled as C++.

There is a small complication that you must deal with when you want to `#include "some_header.h"`
in your C++ unit-test code, and `some_header.h` is one of the C-language header files:

The C++ compiler is going to process `some_header.h`, and it *can* process it correctly *as long
as it knows that* `some_header.h` *is a C-language header file*. To inform the C++ compiler that `some_header.h`
is a C header, you write this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "some_header.h"
}
```

If you don't put `extern "C" { ... }` around the `#include` for a C-language header then you will get undefined-symbol
errors at linktime.

I suggest that you experiment with a project containing the following three files:

**return_one.h**

```
// return_one.h
#ifndef RETURN_ONE_H
#define RETURN_ONE_H

// A C library :)

// A C function that always return 1.
extern int return_one(void);

#endif
```

**return_one.c**

```
// return_one.c
#include "return_one.h"

int return_one(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

**test_return_one.cpp**

```
// test_return_one.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
extern "C" {
#include "return_one.h"
}

TEST(t_return_one, returns_1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1,return_one());  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Get this project to compile, link and run with googletest.

You may find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5335268/1362568) helpful.

Comment: When I try to include only my header file and not the .c file which is to be tested , error: undefined reference to '__FreeRetransmitterQueue'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/SmartTest] Error 1

Comment: When I include my .c file , I get certain compilation issues which is unable to recognize the type conversions      
 error: cannot convert 'MyVersion {aka tagMYVersion}' to 'MyStatus' for argument '2'

Comment: When I include my .c file , I get certain compilation issues which is unable to recognize the type conversions      
 error: cannot convert 'MyVersion {aka tagMYVersion}' to 'MyStatus' for argument '2'                                                     
 There are no such compilation issues when I run ndk-build alone for the project / when I compile my source code in a .c file instead of .cpp

Comment: @user3054298 Sorry, I cannot understand what you are trying to say. It might help if you posted "my .c file" and the compiler commandline that produces the errors.

Comment: The issue i was facing was that implicit type conversions are not recognized in C++ compiler , ..so i had to modify my .c files and use explicit type casting every where. Any way to solve this issue without changing source code? thx for ur help

Comment: @user3054298 Once again, I would need to see the compiler commandline that produces the conversion errors.